# How to know if user has disabled Picture in Picture feature permission?

Tags: android, android-picture-in-picture

[image]

and here is another example:

[image]

from the screenshot above we see user is able to disable picture in picture mode.  you can find it in the "special app access" screen on the emulator api 27 .  How can i detect if user has disabled this feature ?

i tried checking the following but it does not work:

```
packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_PICTURE_IN_PICTURE)
```

compiler states that AppOpsManager  cannot be found. any ideas ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `AppOpsManager.checkOp (String op, int uid, String packageName)`, where `op` is **OPSTR_PICTURE_IN_PICTURE** operation. That method should return **MODE_ALLOWED** constant if supports Picture in Picture operation.

For more info, check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppOpsManager.html#checkOp(java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String)) link.

Comment: I see that the solution is checked, did it work for you? Are you getting the status of pic in pic of chrome?

Answer (score 11):

just like AlexTa said. but i wanted to actually write the code to save someone some time:

```
private fun hasPermission(): Boolean {
    val appOps = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE) as AppOpsManager
    } else {
        return false
    }
    return appOps.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_PICTURE_IN_PICTURE, android.os.Process.myUid(), packageName) == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED
}
```

Comment: If we check this for Chrome, the UID and package name should be of Chrome's, right ?

Comment: why dont you test it out by toggling the setting. im not too sure about that.

Comment: I have done that and when i use my apps UID I always get MODE_ALLOWED.
When I use Chrome's UID I gen an SecurityException

exception uid [My app's UID] does not have android.permission.UPDATE_APP_OPS_STATS.

Comment: if you want to sent user to enable the permission use: startActivityForResult(Intent("android.settings.PICTURE_IN_PICTURE_SETTINGS", Uri.parse("package:$packageName")), 0)

Comment: KitKat, what do you mean? `OPSTR_PICTURE_IN_PICTURE` is available from OREO... So it's not even available for Nougat and have here KitKat...

Answer (score 5):

I might be late but here's the answer

```
private fun hasPermission(): Boolean {
    val appOps = getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE) as AppOpsManager?
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            appOps?.unsafeCheckOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_PICTURE_IN_PICTURE, android.os.Process.myUid(), packageName) == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED
        } else {
            appOps?.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_PICTURE_IN_PICTURE, android.os.Process.myUid(), packageName) == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED
        }
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Permission is available from Android 26+ (Oreo).

On the Android 24+ it's allowed for all apps by default.

It's not available on Android 23 and lower as it's mentioned in some other answers.

So the correct logic would be:

```
private fun hasPipPermission(context: Context): Boolean {
    val appOps = context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE) as? AppOpsManager?
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val mode = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            appOps?.unsafeCheckOpNoThrow(
                AppOpsManager.OPSTR_PICTURE_IN_PICTURE,
                android.os.Process.myUid(),
                context.packageName
            )
        } else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            appOps?.checkOpNoThrow(
                AppOpsManager.OPSTR_PICTURE_IN_PICTURE,
                android.os.Process.myUid(),
                context.packageName
            )
        }
        mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED
    } else {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N
    }
}
```